# How to undelete a file on a btrfs filesystem

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs, deleted-files, forensics

Which software and commands are required, to undelete a file on a btrfs filesystem?

Comment: See [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/415132)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Changaco's script to undelete individual files. it can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/Changaco/45f8d171027ea2655d74

It's a cleaned up version of the script from the post in superuser.